# Trek FX2 Cassette Compatibility

Tags: cassette, trek

Would this cassette work on my 2020 trek FX2?

My old cassette is worn out, and I want a bigger first gear. My bike gearing is 3x8, with the current cassette being 11-32. Also, is it too cheap to be any good?

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MSGHY11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MSGHY11)

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Can we assume that none of the stock components have been switched?  That you have the original 28/38/48 chainrings and the long cage Acera M360?

Comment: `Also, is it too cheap to be any good?` IMO, yes. I wouldn't run that on a bike whose duties extended beyond quick errands around the neighborhood.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll go to the bike shop and see what they can do/ recommend.

Comment: @jeff you've managed to create a separate account, different to the one used to post the question.   Please use your original account.

Answer (score 6):

Your existing derailleur probably won't be able to handle the largest cogs on that.

If you could finagle an adjustment that worked, you might have issues with your chain being too short for the large chainring + large cassette cog combination. Granted, especially on a triple crankset, "cross chaining" like that isn't a good practice as you can achieve nearly the same gear ration with a straighter (more efficient) chainline with your middle chainring.

To summarize:

- your derailleur probably can't cope with such large cogs
- your chain is probably too short if it could
- if you had a longer chain, your derailleur probably couldn't take up all of the slack when your in the small chainring
- (speculation) it's probably not that good of a cassette
- if you have a bike shop nearby, get authentic parts from them. Pennywise + pound-foolish and all that.